# F# how do I correctly insert module references

Tags: f#

I have written some solutions to Advent Of Code 2019 using Visual Basic for Application.  I've also had some fun translating these solutions to other languages (currently C#, Rust, Nim and Typescript).  As a further challenge I thought I'd have a bash at F#.  However I'm stumped on how to cross refer to modules.  My code seems to follow examples I've googled but I'm still getting an error

```
The Value, namespace, type or module 'day01' is not defined
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and the two files I have are

Program.fs

```
namespace AoC2019

module MainProgram =

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "Advent of Code 2019 in F#"
        printfn "%i" (day01.ComponentFuel 10)
        0 // Return an integer exit code
```

and, Day01.fs

```
namespace AoC2019

module day01 =

    let rec ComponentFuel ipComponent =
        let myFuel=(ipComponent/3)-2
        if myFuel <= 0 then
            0
        else
            myFuel + (ComponentFuel myFuel)
```

The line that is causing the error is

```
printfn "%i" (day01.ComponentFuel 10)
```

Update as requested the .fsproj file. For those who are new to f#/Visualstudio the .fsproj file does not appear as a file in the solution explorer but is loaded into a editing window if you click on the name of the project.  i.e. the line under 'Solution 'ProjectName' (X of Y) project).

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Day01.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Note that F# the order you declare files is of importance. So make sure that in the project that `Day01.fs` is before `Program.fs`. You can copy `day01` into `Program.fs` before `MainProgram` to and it should work AFAICT.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer.  Thanks for the advice.  Copying to Program.fs as you suggest shows that everything compiles OK. However, your advice is akin to a lot of the F# documentation I'm reading, which is that it is meaningful if you already know the F# environment. In Visual Studio 2019 solution explorer, Day01.fs is listed before Project.fs, but I still get the error.  So how do I ensure that Day01.fs is seen before Program.fs?

Comment: Perhaps you should share the `.fsproj` file as well. That should help people problemshooting this

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer I've uploaded the .fsproj file.  In looking for the .fsproj file I closed visual studio as I didn't realise I could click on the project name in the solution explorer.  On reopening the project all was correct!!  I hadn't saved the project since creating it before asking my question.  It would seem that it was necessary to save the project to  get things to register properly. I tested this hypothesis by adding a copy of day01 as day02 updating as necessary to make sure the function declaration was unique.  I get the same error with day02 underlined.

Comment: Further experimentation shows that if I add a file to the project, the content of the file is not understood until that file is saved.

Comment: To get rid of such invalid error messages, close and reopen VS after you initially create a solution, or after opening a solution when there is no .vs file in the solution root. The explanation is that as long as there is a .vs folder when you open a solution, all will be fine. This annoying problem is perhaps the same as in this issue report, which I reported all the way back in 2017 : https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3510

Comment: More research show that I was slightly wrong - it's a bug I haven't encountered before, and it's only there right after a solution is created. You can close and reopen VS to get rid of the problem. I was wrong about the .vs folder. I'm filing a new issue on GitHub.

Comment: Issue filed : https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8760

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the F# compiler and/or VS.

Issue filed here : https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/8760